There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first error
I've successfully populated values from a MySQL table into a combobox for search filtering, and it's functioning well except sometimes I'm getting an error:

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.'

when changing the inputs.
I have used asynchronous handling method below and still I'm getting that error.
internal async Task<DataSet> RunQueryWithParamsAsync(string query, MySqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    try
    {
        await OpenDBConnectionAsync();

        using (var command = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            if (parameters != null && parameters.Length > 0)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            }

            using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                var dataSet = new DataSet();
                var dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataTable.Load(reader);
                dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);
                reader.Close();
                return dataSet;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception or handle it as needed
        throw new Exception("An error occurred while executing the query.", ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        await CloseDBConnectionAsync();
    }
}



My guess is that you've got a single connection, and that may be shared across multiple commands. Instead of doing that, create a new connection each time you need to interact with the database, and let the underlying connection pooling handle any appropriate sharing. (Obviously use using statements appropriately so that it's clear when the connection can be reused.)

Thank you very much @Shadow it was the problem and i created a new connection each time i use the db and apparently it is fine. thank you again <3

If you're not already, create the connection object with a using statement too. You can modify your OpenDBConnectionAsync method to create, open and return a new connection object each time, then use using (var connection = await GetOpenDBConnectionAsync()).

By the way, there's no point creating a DataSet if all you're using is a single DataTable. Maybe you make use of the DataSet outside that code but, if not, just use the DataTable on its own.

hi @jmcilhinney Thank you for your comment. I have updated the code above. could you please check whether it is ok?

@udd_ish, don't change your question. Add an answer.

sure @jmcilhinney i rollback to early code in the question and posted my updated code in a new answer

I have updated the code. According the suggestions, the problem was that I was making one connection and sharing it with many transactions. That caused this error. I have added a new connection inside a using block to make sure that I am creating a new connection for each transaction—and, whenever it is done, it gets closed because of the using block—so there will be no further blocking. Thank you very much for the suggestions.
internal async Task<DataSet> RunQueryAsync(string query)
{
    try
    {
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync();

            using (var command = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    var dataSet = new DataSet();
                    var dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataTable.Load(reader);
                    dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);
                    return dataSet;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("An error occurred while executing the query.", ex);
    }
}

